# Open html element by id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to find the answer here but nothing has been working. Can u guys help me?

I have a loop in my logged page what loops "forklifts" from the database. In every bar, I have hidden modal what I want to show on button click. the modal has an id of a looped forklift (otherwise it opens all modals). This code doesn't work and I don't know why.

**js**

```
function open_broken_modal(id){
    $("#" + id).css("display", "block");
    //$(".modal_bg").css("display", "block");
}
```

**css**

```
z-index:250;
position:fixed;
top:75px;
left:calc(50% - 300px);
width:600px;
height:500px;
background-color:white;
border:2px solid red;
border-radius:2px;
display:none;
```

**php & html**

```
<div id="<?php print $forklift_id; ?>" class="forklift_broken_modal">
                            <div id="modal_info_wrapper" class="modal_info_wrapper">
                                <h1 class="forklift_number_h" id="forklift_number_b"><?php print $forklift_id; ?></h1>
                                <h2 class="forklift_name_h" id="forklift_name_b"></h2>
                                <div class="forklift_info_box">
                                    <p class="forklift_info_p" id="forklift_info_b"></p>
                                </div>  
                                <h2 class="forklift_name_h">charging spot</h2>
                                <p class="forklift_info_p" id="forklift_chargin_b"></p>
                            </div>
                            <form action="">
                                <div class="modal_input_wrapper">
                                    <input title="this information will be sent to management" class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="broken" value="broken">broken
                                    <input class="broken_info" type="text" name="broken_info" placeholder="write short information how its broken here."><br>
                                    <input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="broken" value="not_broken">intact<br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal_footer">
                                    <input title="this information will be sent to management" class="input_submit" value="save" name="save_broken_details" type="submit">
                                    <button onclick="close_all_modals();" class="input_submit">exit</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

this is only modal, not the whole looped bar. And I have checked that id goes through js function correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code, as you posted a screenshot as a comment on piyush's answer, is that you have several div elements with the same id, in this case 32.

You need to make sure there's only one instance of the same id on the whole document.

The code you posted works fine, I created the following dummy page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.forklift_broken_modal{
        z-index:250;
        position:fixed;
        top:75px;
        left:calc(50% - 300px);
        width:600px;
        height:500px;
        background-color:white;
        border:2px solid red;
        border-radius:2px;
        display:none;
}
</style>
<?php $forklift_id = 123; ?>
<i title="mark forklift broken" onclick="open_broken_modal(<?php print $forklift_id ?>);" class="fa fa-wrench water_logo" aria-hidden="true">click me</i>
<div id="<?php print $forklift_id; ?>" class="forklift_broken_modal">
    <div id="modal_info_wrapper" class="modal_info_wrapper">
        <h1 class="forklift_number_h" id="forklift_number_b"><?php print $forklift_id; ?></h1>
        <h2 class="forklift_name_h" id="forklift_name_b"></h2>
        <div class="forklift_info_box">
            <p class="forklift_info_p" id="forklift_info_b"></p>
        </div>  
        <h2 class="forklift_name_h">charging spot</h2>
        <p class="forklift_info_p" id="forklift_chargin_b"></p>
    </div>
    <form action="">
        <div class="modal_input_wrapper">
            <input title="this information will be sent to management" class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="broken" value="broken">broken
            <input class="broken_info" type="text" name="broken_info" placeholder="write short information how its broken here."><br>
            <input class="radio_btn" type="radio" name="broken" value="not_broken">intact<br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal_footer">
            <input title="this information will be sent to management" class="input_submit" value="save" name="save_broken_details" type="submit">
            <button onclick="close_all_modals();" class="input_submit">exit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_broken_modal(id){
    console.log('clicking!');
    $("#" + id).css("display", "block");
    //$(".modal_bg").css("display", "block");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jeah as i posted it , it hitm me : <div id="32" class="forklift_info">info</div>
this breaks the code?

Comment: it worked now guys, maybe i have been awake just too long .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open only one box then first hide all the boxes by using their classname and then show the box you want to show by id. Like

```
function open_broken_modal(id){
    $(".forklift_broken_modal").css("display", "none");
    $("#" + id).css("display", "block");
    //$(".modal_bg").css("display", "block");
}
```

Comment: what is your click event code.......paste your click event button code too.

Comment: <i title="mark forklift broken" onclick="open_broken_modal(<?php print $forklift_id ?>);" class="fa fa-wrench water_logo" aria-hidden="true"></i>

Comment: And I have checked that id goes through js function correctly.

Comment: verify the id of element on dom, is it printing on. check the style attribute on the clicked item's box is it turn to display block.

Comment: <div id="32" class="forklift_broken_modal">
and i checked in console to change style to modal and it worked. :S

Comment: jeah it works now . thank u guys for all the help u gave me!

Comment: If this answer helped...please mark it as right answer... happy coding :)

Comment: im new here. how can i add answers was helpful?